# Error:Execution failed for task in android studio and not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When I run application in android studio, this error is displayed:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I'm trying different ways to solve this problem:
1-  using clean/rebuild
2- deleting .gradle folder
3- add: multiDexEnabled true
4- add:

```
dexOptions{
    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

5- changed compile to implementation 
but i have problem yet
This is my gradle file

http://s9.picofile.com/file/8320580100/sa.txt.html

Comment: share gradle.build file

Comment: There may be a problem with google service. Please change 
com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2 to com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0

Comment: Seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024672/com-android-builder-dexing-dexarchivemergerexception

Comment: i removed sugar ORM library and this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add multidex library to your dependency and then add `multiDexEnabled` true in `defaultConfig` of your `build.gradle` file.